# How to use VSCode Cordova Tools extension without Ionic?

Tags: angular, cordova, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-cordova

I have an Angular 4.x project, which is wrapped inside cordova to have native builds from it. It works just fine, but I always missed a good debugger for it. Not long ago I found about this extension for VSCode and now I had time to try it out. In the extension's ReadMe there isn't anything written about that you HAVE TO be inside an Ionic project, the only dependency which is listed in it is the cordova.

Still, when I tried to run my project on an Android Device it tried to run an ionic command, which failed of course, because my project is not an Ionic one.

TLDR;
Is there a way to setup VSCode's Cordova Tools extension on plain cordova project?

Comment: It should work fine with cordova, ionic/ionic2 projects. You just need to install extension, choose debug configuration and run debug :) If you are getting this error it means that your project isn't valid.

Comment: I installed the extension, but it isn't working if I'm outside of an ionicX project. Altough the simple cordova commands are working, so it should be a valid Cordova project. I have a `config.xml` and a `www` folder am I missing something what is needed to be a valid cordova project for the extension? (The www folder contains a build of my angular 2 app, of course, so it is not empty)

Comment: post here error message, so I'll take a look at extension's code and tell you what's you are missing.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer. Here is the error message:
`[cordova-tools] Error processing "launch": Error: spawn ionic.cmd ENOENT`
What it looks to me is that it is trying to run an ionic command, which it can't because it's just a cordova project and not an Ionic one.

Comment: Any idea on this error message?